# How to find all links within a div (and all its children elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some logic below that effects all of the 'a' href links on a page - I want to modify this somehow to ONLY effect a href links that are within a div and anymore within child divs...

In this instance I only want to affect the 'Google' link

```
    $( 'a' ).each(function(index) {
        $(this).on('click', function(event){

        });
    });
```

// html

```
<div id='menu'>
   <a href="">BBC</a>
   <a href="">NBC</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div>
     <a href="">Google</a>
   </div>
   <span>Yahoo</span>        
</div>
```

Comment: because you are selecting all the links.... So select the element and find the links in the element.

Comment: I see the downvote police are out again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you only want to find the "google" link, right?
Try this

```js
$('div > div > a' ).on('click', function(event) {
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='menu'>
   <a href="">BBC</a>
   <a href="">NBC</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div>
     <a href="">Google</a>
   </div>
   <span>Yahoo</span>        
</div>
```

Comment: that is correct with what i am trying to do :) will give this a go now thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use bind event handler using class selector.

```
$('.container > div').on('click', 'a', function() {
});
```